# D3 in react is creating multiple graphs of value update

Tags: d3.js

I am trying to update the color of the graph, on updating, all the previous graphs are also visible

Here is my code:-

```
class BarChart extends Component {
  state = {
    color: "green",
  };
  
  componentDidUpdate = (prevProps, prevState) => {
    if (prevState.color != this.props.color) {
      this.drawChart();
    }
  };

  drawChart() {
    const data = [12, 5, 6, 6];
    
    const svg = d3
      .select("body")
      .append("svg")
      .attr("width", 400)
      .attr("height", 400)
      

    svg
      .selectAll("rect")
      .data(data)
      .enter()
      .append("rect")
      .attr("x", (d, i) => i * 70)
      .attr("y", (d, i) => 400 - 10 * d)
      .attr("width", 65)
      .attr("height", (d, i) => d * 10)
      .attr("fill", this.props.color);

    svg
      .selectAll("text")
      .data(data)
      .enter()
      .append("text")
      .text((d) => d)
      .attr("x", (d, i) => i * 70)
      .attr("y", (d, i) => 400 - 10 * d - 3);
svg.data(data).exit().remove();
  }

  render() {
    return <div>{this.drawChart}</div>
    );
  }
}
```

I've figured that I need to change the selectAll part, but don't know exactly how to change it?

Answer (score 1):

You need to include an `.exit` declaration

```
svg
  .selectAll("text")
  .data(data)
    .exit()
    .remove()

svg
  .selectAll("rect")
  .data(data)
    .exit()
    .remove()
```

http://bl.ocks.org/alansmithy/e984477a741bc56db5a5

You may want to instead use a `.selectAll("g")` element/container to avoid having to maintain 'text' and 'rect' selections separately.

Comment: tried adding this in the end, but not getting the result. Can you please check the edit